# Responsive image grid, with cropped and centered images in CSS

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to create a responsive website with a 3x4 image grid where images of varying sizes are cropped and centered within the grid boxes.The images crop but I can't get the boxes to react while keeping the aspect ratio.

The grid boxes are currently a fixed value size because when I try to set it to Width:100% Height:auto it doesn't display the grid and I'm not sure why,the fixed size causes the columns to collapse causing weird margins.

I haven't yet learned js and jquery so if possible I'd like to stick within CSS if possible.

```
   <div class="maincontent">
    <div class="imgrid"> 
       <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://i.imgur.com/09YFTfL.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And css so far:

```
.maincontent{
padding-top: 0%;
padding-left:0%;
}


.col {
    float: left;
    padding: 1%;
}
.col-lg{
    float:left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

/* Images crop and center to col-lg box up to 1000% centering (if 100% if 
it's 3x the size it doesn't fully center)Idk man why? projectors and stuff? 
*/
.col-lg img{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000%;
    right: -1000%;
    top: -1000%;
    bottom: -1000%;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/qowavucico/1/edit?html,css,output

EDIT: This is the effect I'l looking for,
https://jsbin.com/puqehemoxa/edit?html,css,output

How ever when using these values for the code I posted before ( with the auto cropping)  changing the height:auto; width:31.3%; padding: 1%; turns the images into responsive 2 column pancakes.

https://jsbin.com/cejuseroxo/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using css flex box. See sample below.

```css
.maincontent{
 padding-top: 0%;
 padding-left:0%;
}

 
.col {
 /**float:left; dont need this**/
 padding: 1%;
}
.col-lg{
 /**float:left; dont need this**/
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    flex-basis: 30%;
}

  /* Images crop and center to col-lg box up to 1000% centering (if 100% if it's 3x the size it doesn't fully center)Idk man why? projectors and stuff? */
.col-lg img{
 display:block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000%;
    right: -1000%;
    top: -1000%;
    bottom: -1000%;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
.imgrid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="maincontent">
        <div class="imgrid"> 
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://i.imgur.com/09YFTfL.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div> 
        </div>
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! However this messes with the boxes being a set aspect ratio, I updated the post with code that worked previously without the auto crop  as an example if you'd care to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

A non-flexbox answer is also possible by giving your container a width (100vw in my example below) and then using a `calc()` expression for your `.col-lg` width and height, like this:

```
.imgrid {
    width: 100vw;
}
.col-lg {
    height: calc(calc(100vw / 8) - 60px)); /* 1/3 container width because we have three columns, minus margins around the boxes */
    width: calc(calc(calc(100% / 3) - 60px) * 1.0752688); /* original aspect ratio of 400x372; 400/372 = 1.0752688 */ 
    margin: 10px;
}
```

The code snippet below takes that basic principle but adjusts the margins/padding slightly to help center things better. You may have to tinker with the numbers a bit to fit your actual use case.

```css
body {
    margin: 0; /* not strictly necessary */
}
.maincontent{
    padding-top: 0%;
    padding-left: 0%;
}
.imgrid {
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 10px;
}
.col {
    float: left;
    padding: 1%;
}
.col-lg{
    float: left;
    width: calc(calc(calc(100% / 3) - 60px) * 1.0752688);
    height: calc(calc(100vw / 3) - 60px);
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0; /* make up for lack of margin collapse */
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* make our width calculation simpler because of the 1% padding we don't need to account for this way */
}
.col-lg img{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000%;
    right: -1000%;
    top: -1000%;
    bottom: -1000%;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="maincontent">
        <div class="imgrid"> 
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://i.imgur.com/09YFTfL.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-lg "><img src="http://imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg" alt=""></div> 
        </div>
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond! I forgot to mention trying to keep the aspect ratio the same, I've edited my post to reflect that. I had a similar result when I tried setting width to auto but height to a set px size. I can't wrap my head around why height auto works in my second link  without the auto crop but not in my third with the auto crop.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Well I checked out the link you edited into your post, but I only see one giant image, so not sure what's going on there. Nevertheless, I updated my answer above to maintain aspect ratio. Just a little fancier on the math in the `calc()` is all. Is that what you're going for?

Comment: Yes thank you. :) Now to figure out how to keep the crop the same.

Comment: If the above doesn't do what you need, then I must be confused about what you're asking. You'd need to update your link to the effect you're looking for (currently broken) for me or someone else to help you further.